# Porter and Lancaster stemming clarification

Tags: nlp, nltk, stemming, porter-stemmer, nltk-book

I am doing `stemming` using `Porter` and `Lancaster` and I find these observations:

```
Input: replied
Porter: repli
Lancaster: reply


Input:  twice
porter:  twice
lancaster:  twic

Input:  came
porter:  came
lancaster:  cam

Input:  In
porter:  In
lancaster:  in
```

My question are:

- `Lancaster` was supposed to be "aggressive" `stemmer` but it worked properly with `replied`. Why?
- The word `In` remained the same in `Porter` with uppercase `In`, Why?
- Notice that the `Lancaster` is removing words ending with `e`, Why?

I am not able to understand these concepts. Could you please help?

Comment: Actually, a good question!!!

Comment: Nice catch on the quirky behavior of the stemmers, issue raised on the caps output https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2507. Thank you again for helping to catch this!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Q: Lancaster was supposed to be "aggressive" stemmer but it worked properly with `replied`. Why?

It's because Lancaster stemmer implementation is improved in https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1654

If we take a look at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/stem/lancaster.py#L62, there's a suffix rule, to change `-ied > -y`

```
default_rule_tuple = (
    "ai*2.",   # -ia > -   if intact
    "a*1.",    # -a > -    if intact
    "bb1.",    # -bb > -b
    "city3s.", # -ytic > -ys
    "ci2>",    # -ic > -
    "cn1t>",   # -nc > -nt
    "dd1.",    # -dd > -d
    "dei3y>",  # -ied > -y
    ...)
```

The feature allows users to input new rules and if no additional rules are added, then it'll use the `self.default_rule_tuple` in `parseRules` where the `rule_tuple` will be applied https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/stem/lancaster.py#L196

```py
def parseRules(self, rule_tuple=None):
    """Validate the set of rules used in this stemmer.
    If this function is called as an individual method, without using stem
    method, rule_tuple argument will be compiled into self.rule_dictionary.
    If this function is called within stem, self._rule_tuple will be used.
    """
    # If there is no argument for the function, use class' own rule tuple.
    rule_tuple = rule_tuple if rule_tuple else self._rule_tuple
    valid_rule = re.compile("^[a-z]+\*?\d[a-z]*[>\.]?$")
    # Empty any old rules from the rule set before adding new ones
    self.rule_dictionary = {}

    for rule in rule_tuple:
        if not valid_rule.match(rule):
            raise ValueError("The rule {0} is invalid".format(rule))
        first_letter = rule[0:1]
        if first_letter in self.rule_dictionary:
            self.rule_dictionary[first_letter].append(rule)
        else:
            self.rule_dictionary[first_letter] = [rule]
```

The `default_rule_tuple` actually comes from the whoosh implementation of the [paice-husk stemmer](https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/src/e344fb64067e45d47ec62dc65a75a50be51264a7/src/whoosh/lang/paicehusk.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) which aka as the Lancaster stemmer https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1661 =)

## Q: The word In remained the same in Porter with uppercase In, Why?

This is super interesting! And most probably a bug.

```py
>>> from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
>>> porter = PorterStemmer()
>>> porter.stem('In')
'In'
```

If we look at the code, the first thing that `PorterStemmer.stem()` does it to lowercase, https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/stem/porter.py#L651

```py
def stem(self, word):
    stem = word.lower()

    if self.mode == self.NLTK_EXTENSIONS and word in self.pool:
        return self.pool[word]

    if self.mode != self.ORIGINAL_ALGORITHM and len(word) <= 2:
        # With this line, strings of length 1 or 2 don't go through
        # the stemming process, although no mention is made of this
        # in the published algorithm.
        return word

    stem = self._step1a(stem)
    stem = self._step1b(stem)
    stem = self._step1c(stem)
    stem = self._step2(stem)
    stem = self._step3(stem)
    stem = self._step4(stem)
    stem = self._step5a(stem)
    stem = self._step5b(stem)

    return stem
```

But if we look at the code, everything else returns the `stem`, which is lowercased but **there are two if clauses that returns some form of the original `word` that hasn't been lowercased!!!**

```py
if self.mode == self.NLTK_EXTENSIONS and word in self.pool:
    return self.pool[word]

if self.mode != self.ORIGINAL_ALGORITHM and len(word) <= 2:
    # With this line, strings of length 1 or 2 don't go through
    # the stemming process, although no mention is made of this
    # in the published algorithm.
    return word
```

The first if clause checks if the word is inside the `self.pool` which contains the irregular words and their stems.

The second checks if the `len(word)` <= 2, then return it's original form, which in the case of "In" the 2nd if clause returns True, thus the  original non-lowercased form returned.

## Q: Notice that the Lancaster is removing words ending with `e` in "came", Why?

Not surprisingly also coming from the `default_rule_tuple` 
 https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/stem/lancaster.py#L67, there's a rule that changes `-e > -` =)

### Q: How do I disable the `-e > -` rule from `default_rule_tuple`?

(Un-)fortunately, the `LancasterStemmer._rule_tuple` object is an immutable tuple, so we can't simply remove one item from it, but we can override it =)

```py
>>> from nltk.stem import LancasterStemmer
>>> lancaster = LancasterStemmer()
>>> lancaster.stem('came')
'cam'

# Create a new stemmer object to refresh the cache.
>>> lancaster = LancasterStemmer()
>>> temp_rule_list = list(lancaster._rule_tuple)
# Find the 'e1>' rule.
>>> lancaster._rule_tuple.index('e1>') 
12

# Create a temporary rule list from the tuple.
>>> temp_rule_list = list(lancaster._rule_tuple)
# Remove the rule.
>>> temp_rule_list.pop(12)
'e1>'
# Override the `._rule_tuple` variable.
>>> lancaster._rule_tuple = tuple(temp_rule_list)

# Et voila!
>>> lancaster.stem('came')
'came'
```